# Php using post method says that the parameters are missing

Tags: php, postman

I am using the `curl` to access a php to do a `POST` method. The problem it's that using the `POST` method, the `if` it's not working and I get the error that the parameters are missing. 
The php code:

```
if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('title','email', 'message'))){
if(isset($_POST['title']) and isset($_POST['message'])){

        //creating a new push

        //if the push don't have an image give null in place of image
        $push = new Push(
                $_POST['title'],
                $_POST['message'],
                null
            );


    //getting the push from push object
    $mPushNotification = $push->getPush(); 

    //getting the token from database object 
     echo $devicetoken = $db->getTokenByEmail('irina@yahoo.com');

    //creating firebase class object 
    $firebase = new Firebase(); 

    //sending push notification and displaying result 
    echo $firebase->send($devicetoken, $mPushNotification);
}else{
    $response['error']=true;
    $response['message']='Parameters missing';
}
```

POSTMAN screenshot:
[image]

The `isThereParametersAvailable` function:

```
function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

    foreach($params as $param){
        if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
            return false; 
        }
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Notice how it says _query params_ there where you entered those values? Those should instead be in the `Body` section to begin with … https://www.toolsqa.com/postman/post-request-in-postman/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send the parameters is the body section to get the in the $_POST.

See image below.

[image]

```
<?php 


if(isset($_POST['header'])) {
    echo 1;
}
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['header'])` < that will always be considered as being set. It should be inside a conditional statement or as a ternary operator.